# codeigniter 2.2.0 $this->input->post returns false

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, input

I have a text input in a form.

```
<form role="form" id="form" class="form-signin" method="post" action="">
    <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" >
    ...
</form>
```

I want to get input value in controller; When I print or `var_dump ($this->input->post('email'));` it returns false.

How can I get this value. Thank you..

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` returns something?

Comment: no it returns an error "Undefined index: email"

Comment: The item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist. Try `$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter`
 and 
`$this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter`

Comment: Why you have mention the `name=email` two times ? remove one and see if you can get anything in the controller using `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: i just wrote wrong when i asked. it is not 2 times in my code

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` returns `Undefined index: email`? Does not make any sense, we are not asking for any index. How are you submitting the form?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `http://www.yoursite.com` instead of `http://yoursite.com` .

Answer (score 0):

MAke sure your form has an action value to the function you want to submit the form values to.

```
<form role="form" id="form" class="form-signin" method="post" action="Controller/function">
    <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" >
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
...
</form>
```